Double or triple period lesson distribution in aSc timetable
Our school has some single period lessons, some double period lessons, and some triple period lessons. When creating a timetable with aSc timetable, I want the double and triple period lessons to not be in the first place.
How do i set up a double or triple-period class in aSc timetables so that these aren't placed at the beginning of the day?
Our school has some single period lessons, some double period lessons, and some triple period lessons. When creating a timetable with aSc timetable, I want the double and triple period lessons to not be in the first place.
